# center child element, adjust parent accordingly

Tags: jquery, css, slider, jquery-animate, center

I have what is essentialy an image slider. I have a list of images:

```
 <div class="container">
      <img src=""/>
      <img src=""/>
      <img src=""/>
      <img src=""/ class="middle">
      <img src=""/>
      <img src=""/>
      <img src=""/>
      <img src=""/>
 </div>
```

Left
Right

The goal is: When a user clicks either right or left, I will move the first or last image, to the other end of the string, move class="middle" to the next image (depending on which button is pressed), and then animate so that .middle gets moved back to the center of the screen. Problem is, I don't know if it's possible (using jquery) to center a child element, and then adjust all the other children and parent accordingly. Thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var $imgmiddle = $('img.middle');
var imgwidth = $imgmiddle.width();
var docwidth = $(document).width();
var newleft = docwidth/2 - imgwidth/2;
var imgleft = $imgmiddle.position().left;  // position inside container
$('div.container').offset({left: (newleft-imgleft)});
```